# Running failed test using RetryAnalyzer - not working as expected for test using data provider

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using IRetryAnalyzer for running failed test cases and using IAnnotationTransformer for setting annotation at run time. For @Test using data provider its giving strange result.

I have set retry limit 3, that is test should re-run 3 times. Issue is :
If test fails for first data set, then it retries 3 times (as expected). Then for all remaining data set - re-run count is 2. I am not sure, its 2 retries or its 1 run 1 retry.

Here is class implementing data provider:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "data-source")
public void toolbarActionsOnShapes(String selectShape)
        throws InterruptedException {

    Assert.assertTrue(false);
   }

@DataProvider(name = "data-source")
public Object[][] allShapes() {
    return new Object[][] { { "Rectangle" }, { "Circle" }, { "Triangle" }

    };

}
```

}

On running this i get output :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FxercluPinPiOOUAZKe_dMa6NvVMCE0j

For every set of data, if test fails - there should be 3 retries. Dummy project zip is attached for reference. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mt7V2TO4TWRKU9dN4FIFzprkDingUKaE
Thanks !!

Comment: Please retry your scenario using TestNG `7.0.0-beta1` (latest released version as of today). If the problem persists please edit your question and include sample code in the question instead of sharing a google drive link for the project. You could also upload your project into github.com and share a link to the project.

Comment: I was using version 6.14.3. I tried using version &.0.0-beta1. With this version, test are not re-run after first set of data in data provider. Here is sample project : https://github.com/reactJestuser/RetryAnalyzerExample

Comment: Also, when i run test on windows output shows SKIPPED for retries then fail. While on running in docker which has linux environment, output shows PASS for retries then fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug that exists in TestNG `7.0.0-beta1`. Please see [GITHUB-1946](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1946) for more details.

I went ahead and fixed this as part of my pull request [PR-1948](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1948)

Please make use of TestNG `7.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to get past this problem. This should be part of the upcoming TestNG `7.0.0-beta2` (or) `7.0.0` (final release). Its not decided on this part yet.