# TestNG - Retry analyzer not working with multiple test data permutation

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a scenario where I need to retry failed cases, for which I am using RetryAnalyzer. Each test case has multiple test data under data provider.
For e.g.

```
@Test(dataProvider="sampleTest")
    public void testData(final String data){
        Assert.fail(data);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] sampleTest(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {"data1"},
                {"data2"},
                {"data3"}
        };
    }
```

I need to retry each failed test data 2 times for which I used RetryAnalyzer and here is the code

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    int retryCounter = 0;
    int retryLimit = 2;

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RetryAnalyzer.class.getName());

    //Re-try running only the failed tests until retryLimit is reached
    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
            if (retryCounter < retryLimit) {
                retryCounter++;
                log.info("Retrying test: " + iTestResult.getName() + " for "+ retryCounter +" time.");
                return true;
            } else {
                log.info("Test failed: " + iTestResult.getName() + " after retrying for "+ retryCounter +" time.");
                //I am resetting this counter so that if test case is marked as failed for a particular test data, subsequent test data retry must start from 0 count
                retryCounter = 0;
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Problem:
The first test data if failed runs 3 times (1 actual + 2 retries), and the subsequent cases runs 3 more times the previous run i.e `data1` will run 3 times, `data2` 6 times and `data3` 9 times.

```
TestNG version - 6
```

Am i missing anything here? Why is the retries doubling for subsequent test data? I couldn't find anything helpful outside, any help here will be highly appreciated!

Thank You.

Comment: I tried running this code and it is working fine. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53867578/7804477 .This is a related issue for retry analyzer. may be you could try updating testng to the latest version. Also please specify the exact version of testng in question. Is it `6.0` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with TestNG version. After upgrading the version to 7, the issue was resolve, no extra work was needed.

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1946

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1948/commits/7d5e89d72208bc9600efe0d423298d45146d15d8